# Accessing gmail through imaplib with proxy authentification

Tags: python, sockets, imaplib

I am getting crazy. I tried one of solutions to get through proxy:

```
class SocksIMAP4(IMAP4_SSL):
    def open(self, host, port):

            self.host = host
            self.port = port
            self.sock = socksocket()
            self.sock.set_proxy(PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, 'tmg-array.co.vectis.local', 8080, True, 'login',
                                'pass~')
            self.sock.connect((host, port))
            self.file = self.sock.makefile('rb')
```

And then

```
imap_server = SocksIMAP4('imap.gmail.com', 993)
```

But nothing happens. Process seems to be eternal.

It doesn't throw mistakes and program is like get frozen at the connection stage.

Any suggestions?

edited

my import is

```
import email
from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL, IMAP4_SSL_PORT, IMAP4, IMAP4_PORT
import re
import socks
import socket
from socks import socksocket, PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, PROXY_TYPE_HTTP
import smtplib
```

Comment: Can you include the import lines that you have in your code? For example `import imaplib`

Answer (score 1):

I know it is late but I just want to post an answer for whom don't know.

Replacing three last lines of function `open` by these lines

```
self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, "127.0.0.1", 8118)
self.sslobj = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, self.keyfile, self.certfile)
self.file = self.sslobj.makefile('rb')
```

Comment: when `self.sock` gets wrapped by `ssl.wrap_socket` it gets `detach()`'ed and doesn't work anymore